# gerrit Unable to create changes: LOCK_FAILURE when pushing for review

Tags: git, gerrit

I've been handed numerous git repos which I have created mirrors of. I'm getting following error when trying to push to gerrit for review

```
blake-macbook:repo blake$ git push ssh://gerrit-new/repo HEAD:refs/for/master
Counting objects: 3, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 359 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (2/2)
remote: Processing changes: refs: 2, done    
To ssh://gerrit-new/repo
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (Unable to create changes:LOCK_FAILURE)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://gerrit-new/repo'
```

Gerrit is running as its own user. I've checked the filesystem permissions and have refreshed them just in case

```
chown -R gerrit.gerrit /home/gerrit/review-site
```

Logs are showing nothing useful

```
[2016-09-08 00:07:45,071] [ReceiveCommits-1] ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits : Command CREATE on repo:refs/changes/54/54/1 not completed: LOCK_FAILURE
[2016-09-08 00:07:45,072] [ReceiveCommits-1] ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.git.ReceiveCommits : Only 0 of 1 new change refs created in repo; aborting
```

I've created a group call "Project Leads", granted pretty pretty much every permission in the default All-Projects access scheme, ensured that my project inherits from All-Projects.

I've also added my test user to the Administrators group ... no dice. Same error.

weird thing is that it was working fine 5 days ago. The only thing I have done is check out a new branch, try to commit to the new branch (got the error) and now the error is present for every commit (well, everything I've attempted)

If I bypass review it pushes just fine (suboptimal workaround though)

Any help appreciated

EDIT: in case you are wondering about the ssh server/port i have it set up on ssh config file

```
Host gerrit-new
    HostName        <server>
    Port            29418
    User            <user>
    IdentityFile    ~/.ssh/<priv_key.rsa>
```

EDIT2: also tried restart, reindex, reboot, and manually deleting the write.lock files

Comment: ok, this is weird

Comment: seems to be intermittent now. have managed to get successful pushes after doing the following

* amending the commit and removing the commit id
* changing push.default value from matching to simple
* and finally just by running the push command half a dozen times until it succeeds

still no reliable fix

Answer (score 1):

After our server restarted unexpectedly, gerrit's database data was lost, and the account and submission information were lost. I had to reinstall the gerrit database. When I re-establish the gerrit index, I will reproduce this error. Re-push the local branch to the remote, restart the service, then no longer report this error. Hope can help you.

```
Git remote remove origin
 
Git remote add origin ssh://XXXX@192.168.XX.XXX:29418/you_pro

Git push -u origin master
```

Comment: Along these lines, I went into the git repo (under the ./git/ directory in gerrit) and ran a "git gc" That came back with an error telling me a "./packed-refs.lock" file existed. After I removed this file, all was good and my LOCK_FAILURE issues went away. I also had an unexpected loss of power to the gerrit server.

Comment: In my case I had to force a Gerrit VM to shutdown, because I couldn't shut it down safely. I ran into the same LOCK_FAILURE issue and andrew-geissler's solution fixed it for me as well. I saw the ./git/<repo>/packed-refs.lock file, removed it and now Gerrit is working fine again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you already seen these following old threads?

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/repo-discuss/nvUnY346y14

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/gerrit/issues/detail?id=1593

Maybe they can help you or give some ideas...

Comment: i've looked at those. no help unfortunatley

Answer (score 0):

I just reverted the commited changes back to staging area with command 
git reset --soft HEAD~1

And retried . It worked for me .